# FluBackgroundSession <BA252146-6B6D-4475-9805-10DE8E81F74C> FAILED to UNLINK download file: /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloa

Tags: flutter

In my flutter application, I now have a new error. 'BackgroundSession  FAILED to UNLINK download file: /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/....../CFNetworkDownload_MPwMBx.tmp, errno:1, desc: Operation not permitted
'

The code has not changed, but now I have this error and my application stop working

````
class FirebaseApi_Upload_Files_To_Storage {

  static UploadTask? uploadFile(String destination, String file) {
    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);

      print('Attempting to upload file $file to $destination');

      return ref.putFile(File(file));
    } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
      print('Error occurred while uploading file: $error');

      return null;
    }
  }



```
````